# Complete child field with parent field on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvpDz.png)I have this problem that I need to complete a child field with a value that already exists on parent field, like this:

```
{
  "title":"learning mongo",
  "description":"how to add child field",
  "createdAt":"2020-04-25 09:19:28.285Z"
  "user":{  
    "name":"John",
    "email":"john@gmail.com"
   }
}
```

And I'm writing a script that must use the createdAt value inside user, as below:

```
{
  "title":"learning mongo",
  "description":"how to add child field",
  "createdAt":"2020-04-25 09:19:28.285Z"
  "user":{  
    "name":"John",
    "email":"john@gmail.com",
    "joinedAt":"2020-04-25 09:19:28.285Z"
   }
}
```

I'm using kotlin and mongock-spring-v5 and I wrote this code to do this migration:

```
@ChangeSet(id = "addUserJoinedAtField", author = "Paulo", systemVersion = "2.7.0", order = "047")
    fun addUserJoinedAtField(mongoTemplate: MongockTemplate) {
        val update = Update().set("users.$[user].joinedAt", "createdAt").filterArray(Criteria.where("user.joinedAt").exists(false));
        mongoTemplate.updateMulti(Query(), update, PROJECT_COLLECTION)
    }
```

But when I do this, the result is the field `"joinedAt":"createdAt"` added to the user. How do I pick up the createdAt value instead?

[my attempts and the following results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvpDz.png)

Comment: Try instead of set("users.$[user].joinedAt", "createdAt") this: set("users.$[user].joinedAt", "$createdAt")

Comment: I have already tried this, but when I put the dollar symbol, it turns red with "Unresolved reference: createdAt" problem :/

Comment: Did you try put "users.$createdAt"? Can you send a link to library what do you use?

Comment: I did now, but doesn't work either. It seems like that putting '$' inside a string gives an error because of kotlin string formatting.
https://github.com/mongock/mongock

Comment: You must escape the `$` sign in order to prevent Kotlin from taking it as the start of a string template, i.e. `"$createdAt"` is the same as `createdAt` while that is expected to be a Kotlin variable. If you really want a String containing "$createdAt", you have to write `"\$createdAt"`.

Comment: I don't want to put at the database a string containing "$createdAt". I want to pick each value from the parent and put as a "joinedAt" value inside the user...

Comment: I think you have to use interface of updateMany() i don't know how to use it in kotlin

Comment: I think you missed what I was trying to say. Rostyslav suggested that you write `set("users.$[user].joinedAt", "$createdAt")`, but in Kotlin you can use `$<identifier>` to insert the value of a Kotlin expression inside a String. For instance, if you have a Kotlin variable `createdAt` with value `"x"`, the String `"($createdAt)"` equals `"(x)"`. You replied that you tried what was suggested by Rostyslav (twice), but it did not work, because you do not have a Kotlin variable `createdAt`. Therefore, you have to write `"\$createdAt"` instead to prevent Kotlin from trying to replace the template.

Comment: I'm sorry @KarstenGabriel, I was so involved on this problem I didn't reply you well. When I put `"\$createdAt"` the result is `"joinedAt":"$createdAt"` instead of `"joinedAt":"2020-04-25 09:19:28.285Z"` as I expected.